# How to fit a table to page width in telerik report

Tags: telerik, telerik-reporting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYbqB.png)I have a telerik report with table,the table contains a column group.
Currently if there are less columns there is a blank space on the right side of the page and if the columns count exceeds it goes to the next page.
Is there any way i can fit the table to the page width.

In the report the marks column is a group column. As seen in the image there is a blank space on the right side of the page. I want the column width to change dynamically to fit to the page.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please show the telerik report? You can get more help if you share more information like screenshots. Regards.

Comment: Screenshots been attached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution .

I had to set the binding rules for the column to set its width

Comment: could you please provide some details :)

Comment: You need set binding rule for the width of the group column.   

This is the formula i used 7.87/(Fields.TotalRecords+1)+'in'

Here 7.87 is the width of my report, total records are the no of items in the group and the +1 is the no of remaining rows.

This gives equal width for all the columns in the report